# Spring Data Jpa to query two tables and get results from a third table

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Given a field in Table MessageType and a field in User I want to pull out information that's in Table Results.

This is how they're related :

```
Users

private Long Id;

private String name;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn("id")
private Survey surveydata;


MessageType

private Long id;

private String description;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn("id")
private Results results;


Results

private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn("id")
private MessageType messageType;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn("id")
private Survey surveyData;


Survey

private Long id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn("id")
private Users user;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn("id")
private Results results;
```

What I want to achieve is, given the name of a user and Description of Message type, get all Results.

I create repositories for each. And I tried to make my relationships bidirectional to not have to join.

How would I write the query to do this using Spring Data Jpa ?
From the User I can get the SurveyId and then in the Results table, I have reference to MessageType. I check if messageType.description==to the given parameter.
But I'm not sure how to write this and if it's correct.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you should try to make some JPQL query first before asking us here. Show some effort.

Comment: check the spring data reference documentation to create repository query methods by traversing nested properties available [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

Comment: You have only posted pseudo-code (why?), but the mapping you posted is incorrect. Check the hibernate manual to learn how to correctly map bidirectional associations.

Comment: @JBNizet Because it's bigger classes with more data. I just wrote some of the fields and classes. I see that now, I will edit it to using HashMaps or Lists. Thank you.
Vlasec Thank you. I have tried some things, and my question was wether there exists a method in Spring Data JPA  or should I map it with Query annotation and write an sql query there . If there was a way around joins.
And thank you Amanzoor!!

Comment: @MonG if you have been looking to add a method to ResultRepository, yes you can do it, look at the aforementioned link for further details.